# What exactly happens with alpha colors after blending?

Tags: opengl, gpu, alphablending

I am working on a test project where one big 3D quad is intersected by several other 3D quads (rotated differently). All quads have transparency (ranging from fully opaque to fully transparent). The small quads never overlap, well, they might, but the camera placement and the Z-buffer make sure that only those parts that may overlap actually overlap.

To render this, I first render the big quad to a different rgba framebuffer for later lookup.
Now I start rendering to the screen. A skybox is first rendered, then the small quads are rendered with alpha blending enabled: GL_SRC_ALHPA and GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA. After that I render the big quad again with alpha blending also enabled this time. Of course, only the pixels in front of the quads will be rendered because of the Z-buffer.

That's why, in the fragment shader of the small quads, I do a raytrace to find the intersection with the big quad. If the intersection point is BEHIND the small quad, I fetch the texel from the originally created framebuffer and blend this texel manually with the calculated small quad texel color.

But the result is not the same: the colors in front are rendered correctly (GPU handles the blending there), the colors behind them are "weird". They are lighter or darker but I never get the same result. After consideration, I think this must be because I am not emitting the correct alpha value from my small-quads shader, so that the GPU performed blending changes the colors even more.

So, how exactly is the alpha value calculated when blending on the GPU when using the above mentioned blending method. In the opengl manual, I find: A * Srgba + (1 - A) * Drgba. When I emit that result, the blending is not the same. I am quite sure that this is because the result is again passing through the GPU blending again.

The ray tracing is correct, I'm certain of that.

So, what should I do with my manual blending?
Or, should I use another method to get the right effect?

Not really necessary I believe, but here is some code (optimization is for later):

```
vec4 vRayOrg = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 vRayDir = vec4(normalize(vBBPosition.xyz), 0.0);

vec4 vPlaneOrg = mView * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 vPlaneNormal = mView * vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

float div = dot(vRayDir.xyz, vPlaneNormal.xyz);
float t = dot(vPlaneOrg.xyz - vRayOrg.xyz, vPlaneNormal.xyz) / div;

vec4 pIntersection = vRayOrg + t * vRayDir;

vec3 normal = normalize(vec4(vCoord, 0.0, 0.0)).xyz;
vec3 vLight = normalize(vPosition.xyz / vPosition.w);

float distance = length(vCoord) - 1.0;
float distf = clamp(0.225 - distance, 0.0, 1.0);
float diffuse = clamp(0.25 + dot(-normal, vLight), 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 cOut = diffuse * 9.0 * distf * cGlow;

if (distance > 0.0 && t >= 0.0 && pIntersection.z <= vBBPosition.z)
{
    vec2 vTexcoord = (vProjectedPosition.xy / vProjectedPosition.w) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    vec4 cLookup = texture(tLookup, vTexcoord);
    cOut = cLookup.a * cLookup + (1.0 - cLookup.a) * cOut;
}

vFragColor = cOut;
```

Comment: If your concern is ***not*** blending the result of the thing you already blended, you should either disable `GL_BLEND` or use the blend function (`GL_ONE`, `GL_ZERO`) to replace.

Comment: Your shader does correctly implement `GL_SRC_ALPHA`, `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`... but you could also implement that using [`cOut = mix (cOut, cLookup, cLookup.a)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/mix.xhtml) since what you really want is simply linear interpolation between `cLookup` and `cOut` based on the value of `cLookup.a`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: no, I can't disable blending as the GPU will perform the alpha blending for the parts of the big quad that are in front of the small quads. (I could, of course, also perform that blending in my shader too, but I believe it should be possible without it). Thanks for the mix-tip and for checking my blend-code.

Comment: After some checking: the reason I can't disable blending is because of the skybox, it must also be blended.

Comment: BTW: when disabling the GPU blending, the colors are indeed exactly what they should be, but as I said: the skybox is missing under it.

Comment: Off the top of my head -- you have destination alpha in this case, it might be possible for you to draw the skybox after all the stuff in front of it and then modulate the result by the alpha value *already* in the framebuffer. Usually you use the source alpha for blending, but in this case since you are drawing things in the opposite order, you would use the destination alpha: `GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_DST_ALPHA`. That assumes you clear your color buffer to have an alpha value of **0.0**.

Comment: I am trying what you suggested, but now lots of transparent things just disappear or are almost invisible. I'll look into it further. I would still prefer to see another solution.

Comment: Well, you would have to draw everything before the skybox using `GL_ONE, GL_ZERO` blending. But I did not really think that was a proper solution ;)